# How to run several .txt input files as a test for Java program with output files

Tags: java, eclipse, text, input, cmd

I've been using cmd to run supplied .txt through my java homework because the instructor also supplies the correct output, so we can check that our program functions properly. It looks like this when I do it...

```
...Documents\CSE205\Assignment5>java Assignment5 < input1.txt > myoutput1.txt
```

The instructor pointed us to a file compare tool that will highlight differences between myoutput and the expected output. I just learned that I can compile all classes in the folder with the command `javac *.java`

So I'd like to know if there is any way to feed my program each of 4 inputs to get 4 separate myoutput files through the command prompt or some other way.

Thanks in Advance
macncheese

Comment: Totally botched part of that.  The executing line doesn't show my pointy brackets or input file.  Correction:
...Documents\CSE205\Assignment5>java Assignment5<input1.txt>myoutput1.txt

Comment: Since you tagged the question with "eclipse" you might want to have a look at `Run configurations`. Otherwise try a simple batch? 1st line `java assignment5 < input1.txt > myout1.txt`, 2nd `java assignment5 < input2.txt > myout2.txt` etc. Then you just have to run that batch and done.

Comment: I think I'm more simple than a simple batch.  How do I make it?  How do I run it?  I found a tutorial and tried like you said, including the entire path from c to my file, and I tried it again with "start" at the beginning of the line.  The cmd window pops up and disappears faster than I can read anything and I do not get any output files.  Thanks

Comment: Add `pause` or try to follow my step by step answer below. `start` just opens a new command line window, and `start program.exe` closes that window after execution of the code, you definitely don't want that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a file `run.bat` in your `Assignment5` folder. Edit it (Right-Click -> edit...) and write it like this:

```
java Assignment5 < input1.txt > myOutPut1.txt
java Assignment5 < input2.txt > myOutPut2.txt
java Assignment5 < input3.txt > myOutPut3.txt
...
```

Make sure that the file names are correct and `Assignment5` reflects the name of your MainClass.

Then open your command line (depending on your windows version this might differ a little bit), usually by pressing `Windows + R` (Opens `Run...`) and typing `cmd`. Navigate to your folder (`cd C:\Users\user3277465\Documents\CSE205\Assignment5`) as you should already know.

Type `run` and hit enter. Your batch file should now be executed, without closing the window. You can run it again and again without closing the folder.

Additionally you maybe want to add your compile command as well (`javac *.java`), if so add it simply in front.

And if you want the script to pause, you can also add `pause` - you will need to press a key at those points.

So an example `run.bat` could be:

```
javac *.java
pause
java Assignment5 < input1.txt > myOutPut1.txt
java Assignment5 < input2.txt > myOutPut2.txt
java Assignment5 < input3.txt > myOutPut3.txt
```

It will compile all files, wait for a key input and then run your program with all in- and outputs. The `pause` allows you to interrupt the batch (`CTRL + C`) if there are compile errors without running the program.

Comment: That was AWESOME!! I often find myself fixing formatting issues with my output, and have to recompile everything, then retest the ones I've already passed just in case. This just took a 4 minute job and turned it into a 10 second job.  My problem originally was not trying to run the bat from cmd (duh, rookie move).  Thanks a TON!!